# Journey Builder Audience limit subscribers to send to by day

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there any way inside the Journey Builder to limit the # of subscribers that can be entered each day?  I have an audience size of 15K and wanted to spread that out over the course of 5-7 days at a rate of about 3K.

I know I could do an automation that would specify this, but didn't know if there's a way to do it without running a query to load subscribers in groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Random Split and split a path to 7 and control the % of audience gets into each path. Then set separate wait times per path and then join all paths to a email send activity.

[image]